# removing mitochondrial read and unassembled "random" from multiple bam files

Tags: awk, shell

This is the one i used for a single bam file to filter its mitochondrial as well as unassembled read

```
samtools view -h SRR2920466.bam | awk '{if($3!= "chrM" && $3 != "chrUn"){print $0}}' | samtools view -Shb - > this.filter.bam
```

Is there any way i can do it on multiple files with parallel as i do to index and sort bam files using samtools .

So i tried this ,which is of course not working as its not able to pipe properly because it shows me error regarding additional fonts

```
ls *.bam | parallel "samtools view -h {} | awk '{if($3 != "chrM" && $3 != "chrUn"){print $0}}'| samtools view -Shb {.}.bam"
```

Any help with my above codes? As i get it there is wrong with my pipe .

After updating the samtools to version 1.9 i ran the small script

i get this error

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( != chrM &&  != chrUn){print ./index_sort.sh}}
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( != chrM &&  != chrUn){print ./index_sort.sh}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                    ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( != chrM &&  != chrUn){print ./index_sort.sh}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                   ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( != chrM &&  != chrUn){print ./index_sort.sh}}
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( != chrM &&  != chrUn){print ./index_sort.sh}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                    ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( != chrM &&  != chrUn){print ./index_sort.sh}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                   ^ unexpected newline or end of string
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( != chrM &&  != chrUn){print ./index_sort.sh}}
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( != chrM &&  != chrUn){print ./index_sort.sh}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                    ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( != chrM &&  != chrUn){print ./index_sort.sh}}
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                   ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

I have 30 bam files i tried with 2 to see if its working or not , after the suggestion of @WouterDeCoster i tried the above one after updating samtools . the basic samtool with egrep works but for multiple file i couldn;t do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your awk command is inside double quotes (`""`) which means that all of the awk field variables (e.g. `$3`) are being interpreted by the shell. Since `$3` is not set in the shell, your awk is trying to compare an empty string and that's why you get the error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {if( != chrM &&  != chrUn){print ./index_sort.sh}}
awk: cmd. line:1:      ^ syntax error
```

Note how the error message shows `if( != chrM` and not `if($3 != chrM`. Since you *need* to use double quotes here because you need both an outer (for `parallel`) and an inner (for awk) quote, and single quotes can't be nested, you will have to escape the awk variables:

```
ls *.bam | parallel "samtools view -h {} | 
    awk '{if(\$3 != "chrM" && \$3 != "chrUn"){print \$0}}' | samtools view -Shb {.}.bam"
```

Comment: looks like i need to clear my fundamental  awk concepts let me run and will update you. now i ran your code i get output like this "�&Ct�wh���x�Y#��J�f���{/.i��7��%M`�������`C�̛�<kbb�������B��f����<#?���
                                                                                        :P�y���
u��O��r.�_2ؑ�xu�zl�,xϭ"2�*�Uo�ȩ�@ayi���
/0���/���۶�
               �>�Xh� ��Ί�5h�f~���euSa1����;5��{���R�3L����p%��[<�1)M�y!�w��#���_�`�V5rj��v�}�
S-���y)�Nμ4��Jӕ�D���*n�1��ޥ�g�����y���䒋�N��)���<:���mʲ�溎[�ʘ���K��[punit@localhost chrm]$ 62;c62;c62;c62;c^C
"

Comment: @krushnachChandra well yes, of course. You are printing a bam file which is compressed binary data. What were you expecting to see? If you want sam output, remove the `b` from the options you give to `samtools view`. The `b` makes it print bam output.

Comment: so i idea is after filtering the mitochondrial read and unassembled one i want  bam output written to file with bam format which will be using for downstream analysis.I don't want to print it on the terminal . tried it with -o to write the output seems like i couldn;t make it work..

Comment: @krushnachChandra `-o` should work. Also, you could redirect in the parallel command: `ls *.bam | parallel "samtools view -h {} | awk '{if(\$3 != "chrM" && \$3 != "chrUn"){print \$0}}' | samtools view -Shb  > {}.bam"`. But as I said under your question, the new error is completely unrelated. You probably have a malformed bam file. But please ask a new question about that. Even better, run `for bam in *bam; do samtools view -h "$bam" | head -n1 || echo "$bam file is corrupted"; done` That should help you find the bad file.

Comment: will run it and see

Comment: its working ,the output is written to bam file

Comment: i have accepted the answer sorry i missed it to mark since i saw this thread active again .